# Problem with Amazon links

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, advertising, markdown

For many years, Stack Exchange made some revenue on post links to Amazon products.  It did this by substituting an "affiliate link", a shortened URL beginning with rads.stackoverflow.com.  These links were problematic, and SE stopped doing it, sort of.

SE didn't stop replacing Amazon product links; clicks still go to rads.stackoverflow.com.  It just stopped replacing the associated product link with the affiliate link before resending to Amazon.

Unfortunately, system or browser ad blockers and some browser extensions and applications prevent rads.stackoverflow.com links from working.  Clicking on the product link in a post produces a page saying the site can't be reached.  For more explanation of the issue, see [Given that Stack Exchange no longer adds its referral code to rewritten Amazon links, can we get rid of the link rewriter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334767/given-that-stack-exchange-no-longer-adds-its-referral-code-to-rewritten-amazon-l).

This appears to be due to some recent change since links that used to work now fail.

How can links to Amazon products be included in posts so that they reliably work for all readers?

Comment: Another option: don't include links to Amazon at all :)

Comment: @Joachim, maybe it isn't a software issue.  Maybe it's karma.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been posted on Meta SE, and tagged as a bug, with status under review (see [Auto-replaced affiliate link not working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376235/auto-replaced-affiliate-link-not-working)).

This problem applies only to product links.  Links in the form of an Amazon search with embedded search terms do not get substituted.  So those can remain neat using `[title](URL)` markdown.

Note that while you are editing the post, the edit window and post preview will display the link as you entered it.  If it will get substituted with a rads.stackoverflow.com link, that won't be visible unless it is an actual post. So to verify whether your link will work for all readers, hover the link after posting.

You can make the links visible for yourself by disabling ad blockers or other software that does the actual blocking, or possibly white-listing SE sites. However, other readers may not be able to access the links in your posts. If you post the raw URL, rather than the `[title](URL)` markdown, at least the link will be accessible for readers to copy and paste into their browser. Amazon links can be long, so for now, the most readable way to embed it is as the raw URL in its own "paragraph".

A&C had only a few posts with Amazon product links in markdown format.  I edited those to raw URL links.

If you are willing to invest a little more time, Amazon product links can typically be shortened (see good example [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/posts/10649/revisions)). Very long links are long because they include unneeded meta data, such as how the reader landed on the page, and a title for the product. Most product links can be edited down to the form `https://www.amazon.com/dp/product_code`, where *product_code* is roughly 10 alphanumeric characters that will follow `.../dp/` in the original link.  You can edit the link address in the browser address bar, then click it to test the link edit to verify you remain on the same page. If your edit messes up the link, just hit the back arrow to return to the original URL.